# How do I reboot an AWS instance with Terrafom?

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I have a need to reboot an instance after Terraform patches it but I can't find the resource that will reboot the instance. I know one exists for VMware but not sure about AWS. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [Amazon EC2 Systems Manager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/what-is-systems-manager.html) to run commands on your EC2 instances. Read more about [ssm_document resource in Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ssm_document.html).